# How do I animate my CSS progress bar?

Tags: html, css, progress-bar, animate.css

I have this CSS progress bar right now and it animates great, but I wanted to add complete or not complete markers to it and I have no idea how to add those in there.

So as they go through the progress bar the greyed out 'x' circle will either change to a green check mark circle or the red 'x' circle if it wasn't finished. Right now I just have a progress bar that moves with each step.

Anyone know how I would add the circles to each step??

This is what I'm going for..
[image]

My HTML

```
<section class="container">
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="progress" value="five" id="five">
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="progress" value="twentyfive" id="twentyfive" checked>
 <input type="radio" class="radio" name="progress" value="seventyfive" id="seventyfive">
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="progress" value="onehundred" id="onehundred">
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar"></div>
    </div>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>  <label for="five" class="label">Accept Proposal</label></td>
      <td><label for="twentyfive" class="label">Payment</label></td>
      <td><label for="seventyfive" class="label">Review Documents</label></td>
      <td><label for="onehundred" class="label">Complete</label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  </section>
```

My CSS

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/*
 * Copyright (c) 2012-2013 Thibaut Courouble
 * http://www.cssflow.com
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT License:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */
body {
  font: 13px/20px 'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #464646;
}

.container {
  margin: 80px auto;
  width: 830px;
  text-align: center;
}
.container .progress {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 820px;
}

.progress {
  padding: 4px;
  background: rgba(226, 226, 226, 1);
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
}

.progress-bar {
  position: relative;
  height: 7px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s linear;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s linear;
  -o-transition: 0.4s linear;
  transition: 0.4s linear;
  -webkit-transition-property: width, background-color;
  -moz-transition-property: width, background-color;
  -o-transition-property: width, background-color;
  transition-property: width, background-color;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.progress-bar:before, .progress-bar:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.progress-bar:before {
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
.progress-bar:after {
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 45%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05));
}

/*
 * Note: using adjacent or general sibling selectors combined with
 *       pseudo classes doesn't work in Safari 5.0 and Chrome 12.
 *       See this article for more info and a potential fix:
 *       http://css-tricks.com/webkit-sibling-bug/
 */
#five:checked ~ .progress > .progress-bar {
  width: 14.3%;
  background-color: #86e01e;
  text-align:left;
}

#twentyfive:checked ~ .progress > .progress-bar {
  width: 38%;
 background-color: #86e01e;
}

#seventyfive:checked ~ .progress > .progress-bar {
  width: 64%;
  background-color: #86e01e;
}

#onehundred:checked ~ .progress > .progress-bar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #86e01e;
}

.radio {
  display: none;
}

.label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px 10px;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  color: #464646;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-point">
            <p id="progress_0" class="progressPoint displayNone" style="width: 0%;">

            </p>
            <p id="progress_20" class="progressPoint " style="width: 20%;">
                <input type="radio" class="progressStatus" name="progress_status" id="progress_20_status">
            </p>
            <p id="progress_40" class="progressPoint " style="width: 40%;">
                <input type="radio" class="progressStatus" name="progress_status" id="progress_40_status">
            </p>
            <p id="progress_60" class="progressPoint " style="width: 60%;">
                <input type="radio" class="progressStatus" name="progress_status" id="progress_60_status">
            </p>
            <p id="progress_80" class="progressPoint " style="width: 80%;">
                <input type="radio" class="progressStatus" name="progress_status" id="progress_80_status">
            </p>
            <p id="progress_100" class="progressPoint displayNone" style="width: 100%;">

            </p>
        </div>
      <div id="progress" class="progress-bar" style="width:40%;"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/*
 * Copyright (c) 2012-2013 Thibaut Courouble
 * http://www.cssflow.com
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT License:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */
body {
  font: 13px/20px 'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #464646;
}

.container {
  margin: 80px auto;
  width: 830px;
  text-align: center;
}
.container .progress {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 820px;
}

.progress {
  padding: 4px;
  background: rgba(226, 226, 226, 1);
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
}

.progress-bar {
  position: relative;
  height: 7px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s linear;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s linear;
  -o-transition: 0.4s linear;
  transition: 0.4s linear;
  -webkit-transition-property: width, background-color;
  -moz-transition-property: width, background-color;
  -o-transition-property: width, background-color;
  transition-property: width, background-color;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.progress-bar:before, .progress-bar:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.progress-bar:before {
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
.progress-bar:after {
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 45%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05));
}

/*
 * Note: using adjacent or general sibling selectors combined with
 *       pseudo classes doesn't work in Safari 5.0 and Chrome 12.
 *       See this article for more info and a potential fix:
 *       http://css-tricks.com/webkit-sibling-bug/
 */
.progress-bar {
  width: 14.3%;
  background-color: #86e01e;
  text-align:left;
}

#twentyfive:checked ~ .progress > .progress-bar {
 background-color: #86e01e;
}

#seventyfive:checked ~ .progress > .progress-bar {
  width: 64%;
  background-color: #86e01e;
}

#onehundred:checked ~ .progress > .progress-bar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #86e01e;
}


.label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px 10px;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  color: #464646;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.progressPoint {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: right;
}
.progress-point {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.displayNone {
    display: none;
}
.displayBlock {
    display: block;
}
.progressStatus {
    margin: 0px;
    top: -5px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function currentProgress() {
    var progress=parseInt(document.getElementById("progress").style.width);
    if(progress >= 20 || progress >= 40 || progress >= 60 || progress >= 80) {
        if(progress >= 20) {
            document.getElementById("progress_20_status").checked = true;
        }
        if(progress >= 40) {
            document.getElementById("progress_40_status").checked = true;
        }
        if(progress >= 60) {
            document.getElementById("progress_60_status").checked = true;
        }
        if(progress >= 80) {
            document.getElementById("progress_80_status").checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: You need to update the width of **progress-bar** div and call **currentProgress()** function as you receive the percentage of work completed.
And also the CSS of the radio button used to show progress status.